# Any Known IE10 JavaScript Quirks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

Apologies in advance for the vagueness of this question. I'm going to list as much detail as I know about this problem, which is admittedly not much. Very perplexing.

Background: I have developed a very large app that is almost entirely JS. It passes linting (JSLint and JSHint) even on very strict settings. It works perfectly in:

- IE7
- IE8
- IE9
- Mozilla Firefox 3.5+
- Safari (whatever the latest is on OS X... and probably pretty far back)
- Chrome (all versions)

However in IE10, one part of the app fails to work at all. The strange thing is, it throws no errors whatsoever to the IE10 developer console. No errors thrown in Firebug or Chrome Inspector for that matter either, which is not surprisingly since it works fine in those browsers. After all the code passed all the linting, I took to going over it line by line manually and didn't see anything out of order.

I'm wondering if there are any known quirks to the IE10 JavaScript engine? Googling and searching on SO yielded very little information beyond some extremely specific things that I've already checked my app for.

I could provide a code sample... but it would be a reasonably large file dedicated to the piece of functionality that isn't working (note that this app is very modular, so about 95% of it works).

I am considering just throwing in the  tag to force IE8 mode or something like that if worst comes to worst but I figured I'd throw up a hail mary on here. Thanks in advance for any insight and I realize I've not given much to go on but this has me seriously perplexed. I thought IE10 was supposed to finally fix IE! So much for that.

(fwiw the app uses jQuery 1.7 but no other libraries/frameworks)

edit: From the comments, I am going to try bumping the jQuery version up and see if that helps anything. Barring that, I will post redacted code sample of the 'module' that isn't working! Thanks everyone for the helpful suggestions despite having very little to go on.

Comment: Without any code to inspect here, i doubt you'd get any feedback. Start by breaking your large app into small parts, and from there, build it back until something breaks, Also, if there are known quirks, there must be a whole bunch of those.

Comment: It really is very vague at this point. Have you used the developer tool to debug the code step by step?

Comment: It looks like a good question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it's very modular but you're not using require.js or curl.js?

Comment: If only *one* part of the app breaks, can you possibly show us that part of the code? This is an interesting set of symptoms!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what this module does (ajax, dom manipulation, calculations?) ... that would give some hint as to what part of Javascript or jQuery to look at.  You should also try upgrading to the latest version of jQuery: there have been a lot of IE10 specific bugs fixed between v1.7 and current v1.9.1 (search their bug tracker for 'IE10').

Comment: @thefrontender this sounds promising, I will bump the jQuery version and report back. That is an easy test.

Comment: @coryDanielson ummm.... yeah? why is that hard to believe? neither of those were a good use case for this app and why would you think you know better based on the extremely small level of detail provided here?

Comment: to everyone else, if bumping jQuery doesn't work I will post the code sample. thanks for enduring the vague question!

Comment: The "big one" when upgrading to 1.9 is that `.live()` has been dropped. If necessary, amend `.live()` expressions to the appropriate syntax of `.on()`.

Comment: @mattacular I had an identical issue with no error but it was related to curl.js... full blank white screen.. no console output... it was kind of a nightmare

Comment: if you drop a debugger on line 1 of the code, does it ever hit?

Comment: IE 10 removes some IE-specific features like image filters (which are replaced with CSS3 transitions).  If you were programmatically accessing filters, that would break in IE 10.  Other IE 10 changes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801219(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Some guy had an ie10 problem related to his antivirus. There's a solution on this page. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieitprocurrentver/thread/d3867ae5-1d0d-4190-bad0-91e9afcff175/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will report back tomorrow.@beetroot-beetroot - this app is using .on() for all events but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Just reporting back to say that I am more confused than ever. The app works fine in my reference environment but not on the production server. The app code is 1:1 across environments but there are other unrelated script differences that I'll have to track down. Thanks to everyone and sorry I don't have a better answer. I'll post back if it turns out to be something interesting about IE10/JS